# SystemStackError, stack level too deep when trying to route to controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The error says

> SystemStackError in FacilitatorController#index

but its not a problem with the controller because nothing happens if I change lines in there. It does get to the controller. I think it is probably a routing issue, but I'm not sure what is causing it.

**Link**

```
<%= link_to "Add Facilitators", facilitator_index_path(:course => @course.id), >:method => :get %>
```

**Relevant routes**

```
resources :facilitator
delete '/facilitator', to: 'facilitator#delete', as: 'facilitator_delete'
```

**Some of Controller**

```
class FacilitatorController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @course = Course.find(params[:course])
    if params[:search_field]
      @user = User.select{|user| user.email.downcase.include? params[:search_field].downcase}
    else
      @user = User.where('id not in (?)', @course.facilitators)
    end
  end
end
```

I think it might have something to do with the Courses model having facilitators through an alias, and that conflicting with the facilitator controller?

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
...

  has_many :facilitate_ownedcourses, foreign_key: :ownedcourse_id
  has_many :facilitators, through: :facilitate_ownedcourses, source: :facilitator
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: `resources :facilitator` routes would correspond to the `FacilitatorsController` and not `FacilitatorController`.  Note the plural form - `Facilitators`.

Answer (score 0):

First, You have a typo in your `link_to`, should be `:method` and not `>:method`

Also in your controller

```
@user = User.select{|user| user.email.downcase.include? params[:search_field].downcase}
```

should be something like

```
@user = User.all.select{|user| user.email.downcase.include? params[:search_field].downcase}
```

or still better

```
@user = User.where('email like ?', "%#{params[:search_field].downcase}%")
```

To handle the `case` you can change `like` for `ilike` if you are using postgres, or you can use `lower(email)` if you are using mysql

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a syntax error into "Add Facilitators" link, assuming it's typing mistake.

Secondly, back track would helpful to provide suggestion but couple of suggestion below:

- Check any finder call back
- Iteratively calling a method, may be during before_action  from controller.